# Observatories with public access in Europe

Tags: observational-astronomy, amateur-observing

This is a follow-up to [Observatories that allow public access](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/40366/observatories-that-allow-public-access) with a smaller (geographical) scope.

I am interested in getting to know observatories in central Europe (e.g. France, Germany, Poland, Switzerland, Austria) where you could could go with a class of school children or university students.
Maybe you could add more entries to my list, please?

- The [Effelsberg radio telescope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effelsberg_100-m_Radio_Telescope) has a [visitor programme](https://www.mpifr-bonn.mpg.de/effelsberg/visitors).
- The [Heidelberg observatory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heidelberg-K%C3%B6nigstuhl_State_Observatory) has some [outreach programme](https://www.zah.uni-heidelberg.de/outreach-media-contact/contact), but is close to a city with its lights.
- Similar problems with light pollution has the [Paris Observatory](https://en.parisinfo.com/paris-museum-monument/71190/Observatoire-de-Paris).

I tried to find some European website with such a list, but I was not successful yet.

Comment: Do you only count professional observatories or would you consider to go to one of the amateur observatories, too?

Comment: Ideally professional ones, but not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of possibilities - and often, even when not publicly advertized, many observatories will be very open to find an arrangement when approached, especially by a group of interested audience. So this list IMHO would be the complete list of possible observatories found in central Europe.

The wiki page on [astronomical outreach resources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Astronomy_Outreach_Resources_in_Europe) in Europe has such [list of observatories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_astronomical_observatories) (well, for the whole world, but filter it) - mostly the professional ones; of course it's not complete, e.g. the Thuringian observatory at Tautenburg is missing (who also [offer regularily public tours](http://www.tls-tautenburg.de/TLS/index.php?id=16)) as does the [GEO600](https://www.geo600.org/), the gravitational wave observatory near Hannover.

There are various lists for amateur associations, many have their own observatory, e.g. this one [lists](https://www.sternklar.de/gad/astronomische-Vereine_plz.htm) many in the [DACH countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_distribution_of_German_speakers#Europe) sorted by post code.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, and the links to the lists. You guessed right that I am mainly interested in the sites inside the DACH region, but France is close enough plus many of the group know French so that it is an option as well.